# Why Interface wifi Change every reboot?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wifi, usb

I connected a wifi adapter, I have a different connection configuration for each one but when restarting the interfaces change,
wlan0 -> internal wifi, wlan1 -> external wifi
After reboot:
wlan1 -> internal wifi, wlan0 -> external wifi
And in every reboot it can changes
Is there a way that interfaces are always the same?

Comment: raspi-config : choose "Advanced Options" then "Network Interface Names" and say yes to predictable network interface names - please note, your USB wifi interface name won't be wlan0 or wlan1 - it will be some long (but predictable, i.e. never changing) name

Comment: note: this will also effect the name of eth0 ... it'll be something like enxb827eb123456 where `b827eb123456` is the mac address of the ethernet interface

Comment: Excelent, just what I needed, Thanks

Comment: I've added an alternative workaround in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve stable interface names by enabling predictable network names

In raspi-config, select "Advanced Options" then "Network Interface Names" and say "yes" to predictable interface names, and reboot

However, this will result in `eth0` being called something like `enx010203040506` where 010203040506 is the MAC address for the ethernet port, similarly any USB wifi adapter will be called `wlx020304050607` where `020304050607` is the MAC address of the USB wifi adapter

An alternative method to enabling predictable network names in raspi-config is by firstly making sure predictable names are **disabled** in raspi-config, (this is important as predictable names override manually configured names)

> edit: according to [this raspberry pi forum question](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191639) if you
>
> `sudo ln -s /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`
>
> then you can have predictable names enabled AND override the names using the method below - I have not tested this

Now you can create your own interface names by going to `/etc/systemd/network` folder add the following files (the wlan0 and wlan1 part of the name does NOT matter)

> 80-wlan0.link

```
[Match]
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[Link]
Name=wlan0
```

> 80-wlan1.link

```
[Match]
MACAddress=yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
[Link]
Name=wlan1
```

where `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is the MAC address of what you want to be wlan0 and `yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy` is the MAC address of what you want to be wlan1

Note: according to systemd documentation, manually configuring interface names *should* be enough to override the default behaviour of predictable network names (though, predictable network names are disabled in base install of Raspberry Pi OS, so this isn't really a problem), however in my experience, USB devices still get the predictable network name unless predictable network names are disabled, and any manual network name is ignored - see edit above regarding `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` for fixing this issue

Note2: manually assigned network names don't always play nice with vlan network names configured using `/etc/network/*`